# Calling an activity from Service passing String data

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I want to call an Activity A from a Service in Android(and pass some Strings to it). This activity A inturns calls another activity B with `startActivityForResult().` Basically, I want my service to wait till the result from activity B is obtained. Please give me some idea of how this implementation can be done(and which flag to set in intent)?

**Service**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ActivityA.class);       
intent.putExtra("code",script);
intent.putExtra("type", type);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

**ActivityA**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("code",code);
intent.putExtra("type", type);      
startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: use/register `BroadcastReciver` in Service then if you return from `ActivityB` to `ActivityA` (in `onActivityResult` of `ActivityA`) send broadcast (`Context.sendBroadcast`) ... then `BroadcastReciver` registered in service should do the code from `onRecive`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my Activity A is not getting called from service. What flag should I set in intent. Can you please provide some example link for the same(using BroadCastReceiver)? @Selvin

Comment: first - `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is enough to start Activity from Service, second - you cannot force service to wait until Activity return, thats why you should use BroadcastReciver, third there is plenty tutorial about recivers but you should understand how they works

Comment: @Selvin proposition looks good to me. But why are you performing a long operation in your Activity B ? It seems way more clean to perform it in Service to me (and a separate thread if it can slow down the rendering).

Comment: @Teovald As I cannot use startActivityForResult() inside a Service, I m adding an extra Activity.

Comment: @ Selvin By registering BroadcastReceiver in Service, does it mean, we define onReceive() method in a Service Or should it be done in a separate class(that extends BroadcastReceiver)?

Answer (score 0):

First Create an interface

```
public interface MyActions {
public void doActions();
}
```

Now let your service class implement that interface

```
public class MyService extends Service implements MyActions{
```

and override the method

```
@Override
public void doActions() {
    //Some code
}
```

Now your Activity A is calling B via the startActivityForResult method so override the onActivityResult of A

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //Some code
}
```

In this A class now create a static instance of the interface

```
static MyActions mActions;
```

and now write a static method like this

```
public static void setMyListener(MyActions act){
    mActions = act;
}
```

Now in the onActivityResult that you overrided for class A add this line of code

```
mActions.doActions();
```

so you get

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mActions.doActions();
}
```

Now in your Service class in the onStart() method write this line before calling the activity

```
ActA.setMyListener(this);
```

Thats it done now when from Activity B the call goes to onActivityResult of A and from A the Serivce can listen to the overrided method of doActions()

### Write all your code in doActions() method of service that you wanted to do

Here is the code

1st Activity : ActA.java

```
public class ActA extends Activity {
static MyActions mActions;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act1);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(ActA.this,ActB.class), 15);
        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("Response","requestCode" + requestCode + " resultCode" + resultCode);
    mActions.doActions();
}

public static void setMyListener(MyActions act){
    mActions = act;
}
}
```

2nd Activity : ActB.java

```
public class ActB extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act2);
}
}
```

The MainActivity when app launchs

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Start the service
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}
}
```

The Interface : MyActions.java

```
public interface MyActions {
public void doActions();
}
```

The Serivce class : MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends Service implements MyActions{


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Log.d("Response", "Started");
    ActA.setMyListener(this);
    startActivity(new Intent(this,ActA.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
}

@Override
public void doActions() {
    Log.d("Response", "Listener working");
}

}
```